# Imagen en comando. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Me gustaria saber como hacer que se envíe una imagen sin mostrar el link.

```
await ctx.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/675551876577624083/688189325589872691/1584147395658.jpg")
```

Answer (score 3):

Dado que `discord.File` soporta `io.BytesIO`, una posibilidad es descargarla de forma asíncrona para no bloquear el bot con aiohttp, almacenarla usando `io.BytesIO` y enviarla mediante el argumento `file` tal como Saelyth muestra en su respuesta:

```
import io
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path

import aiohttp
import discord



url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/675551876577624083/688189325589872691/1584147395658.jpg"
img_name = Path(urlparse(url).path).name 

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        buffer = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
        buffer.seek(0)
        file = discord.File(buffer, filename=img_name)
await ctx.send(file=file)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un objeto File, explicado en: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.File

Y luego te recomiendo que leas esto: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.User.send

```
await ctx.send("mira mi imagen", file=miarchivo)
```

Comment: O sea, que descargo la img y pongo la ubicacion?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que no aparezca ningún enlace, una de las maneras de hacerlo es subir la imagen en sí como mensaje.